# Fibered coproduct of $\mathsf{Set}$, as inital objects in $\mathsf{C}^{\alpha, \beta}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, equivalence-relations

(Sorry for the formatting, I don't know how to include diagrams into stackexchange, so I just inserted the photos of the diagram which I made using LaTeX)
Recently I have been studying Paolo Aluffi's book, Algebra: Chapter 0.
Most of the constructions in the book regarding category theory felt like a breeze, until I met this thing, $\mathsf{C}^{\alpha, \beta}$. 
In exercise 5.12, I was asked to define the notions of a fibered coproduct on  $\mathsf{C}=\mathsf{Set}$, by considering the inital objects in $\mathsf{C}^{\alpha, \beta}$. Here was what I did.

Suppose $A, B, C \in \mathsf{Set}$, $\alpha, \beta$ are morphisms $\alpha: C \rightarrow A$,  $\beta : C \rightarrow B$. 
First define an relation ${\sim}$ on $A \bigsqcup B$ to be the **"finest equivalence relation"** such that $i_A\alpha(c) {\sim} i_B\beta(c)$ for any $c \in C$, $i_A,i_B$ are isomorphism from $A,B$ to their "isomorphic copies" in $A \bigsqcup B$ respectively.

Claim: The commutative diagram [image] is an initial object in $\mathsf{C}^{\alpha, \beta}$, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection from $A \bigsqcup B$ onto $(A \bigsqcup B)/{\sim}$.

Proof: 
It suffices to show that for any object in $\mathsf{C}^{\alpha, \beta}$,
[image] , 
there exists an unique commutative diagram [image] 
Define $\sigma:(A \bigsqcup B)/{\sim} \rightarrow Z$ by $\sigma([s]_{{\sim}})=f_Ai_A^{-1}(s)$ if $s \in im~ i_A$ and $f_Bi_B^{-1}(s)$ if $s \in im~ i_B$.

I defined another relation $\thickapprox$ on $A \bigsqcup B$ to be the **"finest equivalence relation"** such that $s' \thickapprox s''$ iff $f_Ai_A^{-1}(s')$ or $f_Bi_B^{-1}(s')$ equals $f_Ai_A^{-1}(s'')$ or $f_Bi_B^{-1}(s'')$ (whichever pair is defined). 
Note that for any $c \in C$, $i_A\alpha(c) \thickapprox i_B\beta(c)$ since $f_Ai_A^{-1}(i_A\alpha(c))=f_A\alpha(c)=f_B\beta(c)=f_Bi_B^{-1}(i_B\beta(c))$. 
So ${\sim}$ must be **"at least as fine"** as $\thickapprox$ by construction.

Here I will have to prove that $\sigma$ is well-defined as a function. 
To show that $\sigma$ is a well-defined function, I need to show that $[s']_{\sim}=[s'']_{\sim} \implies \sigma([s']_{\sim})=\sigma([s'']_{\sim})$. 
$~~~~~~~~~[s']_{\sim}=[s'']_{\sim}$ 
$\implies s' {\sim} s''$ 
$\implies s' \thickapprox s''$ (since ${\sim}$ is "at least as fine" as $\thickapprox$) 
$\implies f_Ai_A^{-1}(s')$ or $f_Bi_B^{-1}(s')$ equals $f_Ai_A^{-1}(s'')$ or $f_Bi_B^{-1}(s'')$ (whichever pair is defined) 
$\implies \sigma(s') = \sigma (s'')$ 
So $\sigma$ is a function. 
The commutativity of the diagram and uniqueness of $\sigma$ follow with a little bit more work.

I felt quite comfortable with this proof for a while, but then I started to wonder whether the **"finest equivalence relation"** in my definition of ${\sim}$ and $\thickapprox$ should even exist. Just as if the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x > 3 \}$ doesn't have a least element.

Is there a more natural, less involved way to define the fibered coproduct, which would evade the current problems with my method?

Comment: I have not checked the other parts of the proof, but the *finest equivalence relation* always exists, as any two equivalence relations have a common refinement, namely $a \sim_{ref} b b \iff a \sim_1 b \land a \sim_2 b$. Analogously any family of e.r's has a common refinement, hence there is always a finest e.r with a given condition.

Comment: There is not a less involved way to define a fibered coproduct (or "pushout") in the category of sets. One thing that helped me at the time was to realize that one can reason using only the "generators" $R$ instead of worrying about determining the exact shape of the equivalence relation $\langle R\rangle$ generated by $R$.

Comment: I have some notes on the subject that I incorporated in my exercise book on category theory [here](https://compose.ioc.ee/courses/2023/ct/exercises.pdf): cf. from page 78 "From here on, until cl.22 we will consider an explicit way to build pushouts in the category of sets..." (just beware of the countless amount of typos.)

Comment: @fosco thanks!! your material was quite helpful

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!